# Find record equals to or is closest to the average using vector C++

Tags: c++, string, vector, struct

How can I find the student’s age whose age equals to or is closest to the average age using vector? I have a function that also does sorting. this is what I have so far using C++ .

```
struct Student{
    int age;
};
double getAveAge(vector<Student>&v)
{
    int totalAge = 0;
    int studentCount = v.size();
    for(int x=0; x < studentCount; x++)
    {
        totalAge+= v[x].age;
    }
    return totalAge/studentCount;
}
double showMedian(vector<Student>v)
{
    Student aStudent;
    if (aStudent.age % 2 )
    {

    }else{

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through your `vector<Student>`, compare each one to the average, compare that score to the closest recorded score so far. If this student is the closest, update the closest recorded score and store the index number of that student. At the end of the loop, look up that student by the stored index number.

That's the English version anyway. And you might need to work on your [abs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs) :)